# Trigonometric identity as a solution differential equation

Tags: trigonometry

I have an identity :

$$ e^{x+1} + y \cdot \csc(y) + \sqrt{1-y^{2}} - \cos(y) = C $$

This is in my opinion solution of the differential equation:

$$ e^{x+1} \tan(y)~dx + \cos(y)~dy = 0$$

In book solution of that differential equation is :

$$ e^{x+1} + \log(\csc(y) + \cot(y)) + \cos(y) = C $$

Are there both identities the same? How could I prove that? Could someone help me with that?

I will be grateful for your help Best regards ;)

Answer (score 0):

First thing First. Why did you not consider that further solving that DE?
Anyways. That DE boils down to   $$\int \frac{\cos^2 y}{\sin y}.dy=-\int e^{x+1}.dx$$

$$\int (\csc y -\sin y)dy=- e^{x+1}+C$$
$$\ln(\cot y +\csc y)+\cos y=- e^{x+1}+C$$
Hope this solves your problem?

Comment: That was not the question, the OP wants to know if his expression is a solution to the DE.

Comment: HE wanted help with the proof @Siddhant. I don't see anything like proving as a solution to DE in OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

it is not the solution of the differential equation you have written because if you take differential of the both sides of your identity then you will get
$$exp(x+1)dx + ({csc(y) -ycsc(y)cot(y) - \frac{y}{\surd(1-y^2)} + sin(y)})dy = 0$$
that does't match with your differential equation.....

Comment: Hmm But: $\int \frac{cos^2(y)}{sin(y)} dy = ysin^{-1}(y) + \sqrt{1-y^2} - cos(y)$ Is that correct?